# Reverse engineering water heater power control board

Tags: triac, reverse-engineering

I am trying to reverse engineer a water heater power control board that I have found in a hot water dispenser. In the original machine, it powers a 2000 W heater (which I will keep) and is connected to another control board which mainly has the microcontroller on it.

I would like to control this board with an Arduino for my own project.

This board uses a TRIAC controlled by a TRIAC driver (MOC3021) but I do not see any other optocoupler to detect the zero-crossing.
Is there another method to detect the zero crossing or is the TRIAC driver controlled by another means?

[image]

**Addition of more details:**
The water dispenser can instantly heat water to any temperature between 45°C to 99°C so I expected a dimming method to control the power delivered to the heater.
If there is no zero-crossing detection, it might only be switching power on and off regularly. To my understanding, it would behave like this:
[image]

With zero-crossing detection and phase angle control, it could behave like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Do you need to detect zero crossing? U1 is probably a microcontroller.

Comment: It may not use zero-cross switching as it will likely be on for prolonged periods of time. The opto-LED might just be left on while heating is required. Zero-cross switching would be better as it would reduce the noise sent through the mains but might be omitted for cost.

Comment: U1 is probably a power supply controller (not an MCU). It sits underneath a small transformer, so it's probably generating the low-voltage supply (via the 7805) for the rest of the control circuit that's connected to all those pins in the corner.

Comment: @DaveTweed I missed the four shorted pins on one side. Linear regulator or power transistor it is.

Comment: @Transistor The water dispenser machine can provide instant hot water with different temperatures. I am assuming the opto-led controls the power timing so it can provide 60°C or 99°C water. That's why I think there must be a  "dimming" logic.

Comment: @DaveTweed Ok thanks !

Comment: Unknown IC can be OPA, for instance LM386. Check the type of sensor, it is probably NTC resistor. Temperature regulator just a trigger with hysteresis. Optotriac you can replace with another with zero crossing, it will improve performance. Do not expect something complicated from cheap controller.

Comment: "*That's why I think there must be a "dimming" logic.*" Since the water heats relatively slowly simple on-off control is probably adequate. See what I've written here: http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/

Comment: @Transistor I have added more details on my main post. If I understand correctly, you are supposing that it works like on my drawing (regular on/off switching) ?

Comment: _”With zero-crossing detection and phase angle control, it could behave like this”_ It could, but it would cost more due to filters so it does not.